# Auth code failing when requiring data from another js file. But works when inside same file - why?

Tags: javascript, firebase, cookies, authorization, spotify

***Still an unsolved mystery. Anyone who finds the answer will now save my project!***

I have an app which requires credentials from Spotify. I am using a template (https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/spotify-auth) to sign in via Spotify but I am changing it so that the spotify client id and client secret credentials are retrieved from the Firestore database.

In order to save the credentials for use throughout the main index.js file, I am exporting the data via a spotify.js file and storing that within a const in the index.js file.

Everything works here apart from the exports.token function: this is the function that stores the auth code (from the address bar) and then uses the auth code in the authorisationCodeGrant. This eventually gets an access token and a refresh token. (see popup.html below for how this looks in the code. None of this was changed but it could be the reason for the problem)

For some reason, the auth code which is used comes back as 'invalid' on the authorisationCodeGrant and this means I don't get the access nor refresh tokens back. See code below:

index.js

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const crypto = require('crypto');

// Firebase Setup
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./service-account.json');
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: `https://${process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT}.firebaseio.com`,
});

// Spotify OAuth 2 setup
const spotify = require('./spotify');

// TODO: Configure the `spotify.client_id` and `spotify.client_secret` Google Cloud environment variables.
const SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');


// Scopes to request.
const OAUTH_SCOPES = ['user-read-email'];

/**
 * Redirects the User to the Spotify authentication consent screen. Also the 'state' cookie is set for later state
 * verification.
 */
exports.redirect = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cookieParser()(req, res, () => {
    const state = req.cookies.state || crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex');
    console.log('Setting verification state:', state);
    res.cookie('state', state.toString(), {maxAge: 3600000, secure: true, httpOnly: true});
    spotify.then(Spotify =>{
      console.log('This is the client id used in redirect ' + Spotify.getClientId());
      console.log('This is the client secret used in redirect ' + Spotify.getClientSecret());
      const authorizeURL = Spotify.createAuthorizeURL(OAUTH_SCOPES, state.toString());
      res.redirect(authorizeURL);
    })

  });
});

/**
 * Exchanges a given Spotify auth code passed in the 'code' URL query parameter for a Firebase auth token.
 * The request also needs to specify a 'state' query parameter which will be checked against the 'state' cookie.
 * The Firebase custom auth token is sent back in a JSONP callback function with function name defined by the
 * 'callback' query parameter.
 */
exports.token = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  try {

    cookieParser()(req, res, () => {
      console.log('Received verification state:', req.cookies.state);
      console.log('Received state:', req.query.state);
      if (!req.cookies.state) {
        throw new Error('State cookie not set or expired. Maybe you took too long to authorize. Please try again.');
      } else if (req.cookies.state !== req.query.state) {
        throw new Error('State validation failed');
      }
      console.log('Received auth code:', req.query.code);
      spotify.then(Spotify =>{
        Spotify.authorizationCodeGrant(req.query.code, (error, data) => {
          if (error) {
            throw error;
          }
          console.log('Received Access Token:', data.body['access_token']);
          Spotify.setAccessToken(data.body['access_token']);

          Spotify.getMe(async (error, userResults) => {
            if (error) {
              throw error;
            }
            console.log('Auth code exchange result received:', userResults);
            // We have a Spotify access token and the user identity now.
            const accessToken = data.body['access_token'];
            const spotifyUserID = userResults.body['id'];
            const profilePic = userResults.body['images'][0]['url'];
            const userName = userResults.body['display_name'];
            const email = userResults.body['email'];

            // Create a Firebase account and get the Custom Auth Token.
            const firebaseToken = await createFirebaseAccount(spotifyUserID, userName, profilePic, email, accessToken);
            // Serve an HTML page that signs the user in and updates the user profile.
            res.jsonp({token: firebaseToken});
          });
        });
      })
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.jsonp({error: error.toString});
  }
  return null;
});

/**
 * Creates a Firebase account with the given user profile and returns a custom auth token allowing
 * signing-in this account.
 * Also saves the accessToken to the datastore at /spotifyAccessToken/$uid
 *
 * @returns {Promise<string>} The Firebase custom auth token in a promise.
 */
async function createFirebaseAccount(spotifyID, displayName, photoURL, email, accessToken) {
  // The UID we'll assign to the user.
  const uid = `spotify:${spotifyID}`;

  // Save the access token to the Firebase Realtime Database.
  const databaseTask = admin.database().ref(`/spotifyAccessToken/${uid}`).set(accessToken);

  // Create or update the user account.
  const userCreationTask = admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
    displayName: displayName,
    photoURL: photoURL,
    email: email,
    emailVerified: true,
  }).catch((error) => {
    // If user does not exists we create it.
    if (error.code === 'auth/user-not-found') {
      return admin.auth().createUser({
        uid: uid,
        displayName: displayName,
        photoURL: photoURL,
        email: email,
        emailVerified: true,
      });
    }
    throw error;
  });

  // Wait for all async tasks to complete, then generate and return a custom auth token.
  await Promise.all([userCreationTask, databaseTask]);
  // Create a Firebase custom auth token.
  const token = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid);
  console.log('Created Custom token for UID "', uid, '" Token:', token);
  return token;
}
```

spotify.js

```
const SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');
// Firebase Setup
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./service-account.json');


function regexIdAndSecret(clientIdOrSecret) {
    const regex = /[(\w)]+/g;
    let n;
    let match;
    while ((n = regex.exec(clientIdOrSecret)) !== null) {
        // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
        if (n.index === regex.lastIndex) {
            regex.lastIndex++;
        }

        // The result can be accessed through the `n`-variable.
        n.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {

            console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);

        });
        console.log(`Found n,  ${n}`);
        return n;
    }

}
class Credentials {

    constructor(client_id, client_secret) {
        this.client_id = client_id;
        console.log('Id in class ' + this.client_id);
        this.client_secret = client_secret;
        console.log('Secret in class ' + this.client_secret);

    }


}

module.exports = admin.firestore().collection('credentials').doc('marc.jwatts@gmail.com').get().then((snapshot) => {
    let client_id = JSON.stringify(snapshot.data().client_id);
    let client_secret = JSON.stringify(snapshot.data().client_secret);
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_id));
    // Credentials.client_id = JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_id);
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_secret));
    // Credentials.client_secret = JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_secret);


    const credentials = new Credentials(regexIdAndSecret(client_id), regexIdAndSecret(client_secret));


    const Spotify = new SpotifyWebApi({
        client_id: credentials.client_id,
        client_secret: credentials.client_secret,
        redirectUri: `https://${process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT}.firebaseapp.com/popup.html`
    });
    Spotify.setClientId(credentials.client_id);
    Spotify.setClientSecret(credentials.client_secret);
    console.log('This is the client id after it has been set ' + credentials.client_id);
    console.log('This is the client secret after it has been set ' + credentials.client_secret);
    return Spotify;

});
```

As I mention, this problem does not occur when the details are in the same file. Does anyone know why the cookie parser part could be breaking due to data being from another file? What's even more strange is that the authorisation codes do indeed work perfectly well - I have tested these on Postman. But they come back as invalid in the code - no idea why! I thought it might be whitespace issue but this isn't it either, any ideas anyone? Got this project in tomorrow night so getting pretty frantic at this point...

Below is the popup.html which invokes the redirect (working) and token (not working) functions:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--
  Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All rights reserved.
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at
      https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License
-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="Demonstrates how to authorize Firebase with Spotify auth using Firebase Functions">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Authenticate with Spotify</title>
</head>
<body>

Please wait...
<!-- Firebase -->
<script src="/__/firebase/6.4.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/6.4.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>

<script>
  /**
   * Returns the value of the given URL query parameter.
   */
  function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search) ||
        [null, ''])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20')) || null;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the ID of the Firebase project.
   */
  function getFirebaseProjectId() {
    return firebase.app().options.authDomain.split('.')[0];
  }

  /**
   * This callback is called by the JSONP callback of the 'token' Firebase Function with the Firebase auth token.
   */
  function tokenReceived(data) {
    if (data.token) {
      firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(data.token).then(function() {
        window.close();
      });
    } else {
      console.error(data);
      document.body.innerText = 'Error in the token Function: ' + data.error;
    }
  }

  var code = getURLParameter('code');
  var state = getURLParameter('state');
  var error = getURLParameter('error');
  if (error) {
    document.body.innerText = 'Error back from the Spotify auth page: ' + error;
  } else if(!code) {
    // Start the auth flow.
    window.location.href  = 'https://us-central1-' + getFirebaseProjectId() + '.cloudfunctions.net/redirect';
  } else {
    // Use JSONP to load the 'token' Firebase Function to exchange the auth code against a Firebase custom token.
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    // This is the URL to the HTTP triggered 'token' Firebase Function.
    // See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions.
    var tokenFunctionURL = 'https://us-central1-' + getFirebaseProjectId() + '.cloudfunctions.net/token';
    script.src = tokenFunctionURL +
        '?code=' + encodeURIComponent(code) +
        '&state=' + encodeURIComponent(state) +
        '&callback=' + tokenReceived.name;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Firebase function fail]

[image: console logs]

Comment: What's the console output and error message?

Comment: The error message is { [WebapiError: Bad Request] name: 'WebapiError', message: 'Bad Request', statusCode: 400 }

Comment: This is despite the auth code actually working on Postman. So I am really unsure what's causing the Bad Request. The only thing that has changed from the original version is using 'spotify.then(Spotify...' instead of just having 'Spotify.authorizationCodeGrant(req.query.code, (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
          throw error;
        }'

Comment: But I mean you have a lot of console messages which might help us trace the logic. Are the client ID and secret actually logged correctly? Just eye-balling the code, `let client_id = JSON.stringify(snapshot.data().client_id);` looks suspicious. It's been a while since I used firebase but I'd expect to use `snapshot.val()` or possibly `snapshot.toJSON()`. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#tojson

Comment: Just added a picture (with hidden secrets) to the question. They are both logged correctly - in postman I use the same as them (in 64bit encoding) and they work fine. I'll try changing the let client_id to both of your suggestions now

Comment: Ah, I remember why I put it as snapshot.data().client_id now. It's because for firestore (not realtime firebase) that's what you have to write to access the values. Putting val() doesn't seem to work

Comment: Weird. Why do the ID/secret need to be stringified? Also, is there a reason you're requiring `SpotifyWebApi` in the index? And what happens if you log out `Spotify.getAccessToken()` from the index?

Comment: I'm glad someone agrees! They apparently don't need to be stringified. And I have taken SpotifyWebApi out of index as you're right its not doing any good there... As for what logging the Spotify.getAccessToken, I get "undefined" as the result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199149/discussion-between-anthonygood-and-marcooz2007).